# Angular: Routing Redirect Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, web-frontend

I am using the router in angular to redirect the user depending on whether he/she is logged in and their current URL:
Below you see the routes from my app-routing-module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuardService] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'}, // redirects to '' exists hence keep this in mind when redirecting
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }, 
];
```

In the situation that the user is not logged in, but tries to access the "/home" directory he/she is redirected to "/login". The code I use to achieve this is.

```
if (accessGranted){
   return true;
} else {
   // tell router to navigate to login pag
   this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
   return false;
}
```

This code basically works, but one error persists: If I am trying to access home without being logged in, I first get redirected to "/", only if I refresh I get redirected to login. I do not really understand why this happens and would love to resolve this issue.

Best regards, 
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
      return this.router.parseUrl(`/login?returnUrl=${state.url}`);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```